# running for loop on array without incremental index

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have this arbitrary multi dimensional array.

```
Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

)
```

I wanna run a for loop to extract the data of each subarray.
But I cannot do a simple for loop because the index (0,5,10,15,1) is arbitrary.
Is there a way to run a for loop then skip the sub array if it is empty?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe foreach? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Since your array indexes are out of order you should use a foreach.

Comment: if you'd've google "how to loop though php array" you would probably have found an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will take `$array` and loop though it, echoing the keys.
You have an array in an array, you can place a foreach in a foreach:

```
// First we take the main array ($array) and loop though its values
foreach( $array as $main_key =>$sub_array){
    echo $main_key.": <br />\n"; // echo the key, some extra html to format

    // the values of the mainarray are arrays themselves, just loop again:
    foreach($subarray as $sub_key =>$subvalue){
        echo '- '.$subvalue."<br />\n";
    }
}
```

---

There's a bit of a trap here if you foreach in a foreach:

```
foreach($array as $key =>$value){
    foreach($value as $key=>$value){ /* ... */; }
}
```

This will create very weird results. The inner foreach uses the same parameter-names and will mess everything up.

Comment: Thanks! That's why our next topic is foreach.

Comment: Based on the comment I'm going to assume you are learning to program. Biggest tip I can give: **Learn to Google what you want**.